# ui-router state forward to a subfolder

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I made two different angular apps (one for client and one for admin) I build the client app on top of express server apis which give me results from mongodb, and I want both to access these apis so the solution I came up with is to put the admin app under a subfolder inside the client project, they are both working fine but because `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');` in the client app. when I hit refresh the browser while inside the admin app, it forwards me back to the client root folder.

My question how to make `ui-router` `state` that forwards to a subfolder without template and controller.

I feel there is a better solution than this please advice,

```
Client => http://localhost:9000/
Admin => http://localhost:9000/admin/rtl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a reverse proxy server which will route incoming requests to the correct server. NGINX is common: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

You could run both 'apps' with in a parent module.

```
angular.module('clientModule',[]);
angular.module('adminModule',[]);
angular.module('mainApp', ['clientModule', 'adminModule']);
```

If you have defined the router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('client', {url:"/client"}
  .state('admin', {url: "/admin"}
```

refreshing the page should direct you correctly.

The Deep State Redirect may help if moving between them: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/dsr

Answer (score 0):

Could you consider changing your folder structure ?

The easier way would be to have the following structure:

```
/ => redirect to /appName
/appName => your client app
/admin => your admin app
/sdk => common stuff
```

This way, you would have completely different states between admin and client app